# Test if the Unix Authentication method is enabled in a mariadb database

Tags: mariadb

I wrote a bash script to backup and restore my MariaDB database. Is there a way to check in a script if the Unix Authentication method is enabled?  If I upgrade a 10.3 database to 10.6 the Unix Authentication method is not available and I need to require the DB root password. I'd like to have a method to check for this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

`Unix socket authentication` is enabled by default since MariaDB 10.4 and statically compiled into mariadbd.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT plugin_name, plugin_library FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE plugin_name="unix_socket";
+-------------+----------------+
| plugin_name | plugin_library |
+-------------+----------------+
| unix_socket | NULL           |
+-------------+----------------+
```

If you can't connect as root user, there are two possible reasons:

- The credentials for root user require another authentication method
- You don't connect to `localhost`. hostname=127.0.0.1 for example connects via TCP/IP but not via unix_socket.

Comment: I'm using FreeBSD as my OS. I've installed Mariadb 10.6 from scratch. My output from that command is the same as yours.

Are you saying that unix socket authentication is install but the plugin is not?  I can login to the command prompt with either mysql -u root or mysql -u root -p.  Not sure what the difference is.

iocage exec wordpress mysql -u root -e "SELECT plugin_name, plugin_library FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE plugin_name="unix_socket";"
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1:

Comment: Look like the above exe needs to escape `"` in the shell. Look at `show create user` to see how the user was created and if it has `unix_socket` there (which should be the case for FreeBSD). `-p` will prompt if password is requested. For unix_socket it isn't requested.